# Java - KeyListener's thread causes concurrent modification. Solution?

Tags: java, concurrency, arraylist, keylistener

My game update loop iterates through an `ArrayList` constantly, I also have a `KeyListener` that when a button is pressed, it adds an `Object` to this `ArrayList`, which seems to be causing a concurrent modification exception.

After a lot of looking around I decided it would be best to try (I'm fairly new to Java) figure out a way to merge key events into the main thread. Given this scenario, how can I do that, or is there a way of doing this which I'm not seeing? Thanks.

**PS:** I could look into more advanced ways but I'd rather try keep it fairly single-threaded and have the key events pass on to the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are running an event loop that you want to add events to the end of in the body.  If that is true, you probably want to use a java.util.Queue implementation, such as a LinkedList and do a

```
while((event=queue.poll()) != null) { 
  /* process event */ 
  queue.add(keyEvent);
}
```

Comment: Well, hopefully with some sort of synchronization, yes, but a queue is handy.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION 1:**

Just do keep in mind that during the iteration process, your key listener will be blocked (that also means your iterator is running on old data as is with Solution 2).

If using ArrayList do this:

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
```

And use this `list` object every where. You have to import

```
import java.util.Collections;
```

I agree with @msandiford Adding how to iterate ....

```
while(some_condition) {
do something
  synchronized(list) {
    Iterator i = list.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext())
        do_something_with(i.next());
  }
  do something else
}
```

This is quick solution if you have outer loop in which you are iterating. So that you are out of `synchronized` block for sometime so that `KeyListener` can add to array list.

**SOLUTION 2:**

If you want to use COW just be aware that whenever an add/update operation happens it will make a copy of the underneath collection and your iterator will not see the the change. But the key listener WILL NOT be blocked (but at this point a new copy will be created underneath).

```
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;


List list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<your_object_type>();
```

For iteration:

```
while(some_condition) {
  do something
  Iterator i = list.iterator();
  while (i.hasNext())
    do_something_with(i.next());

  do something else
}
```

**SOLUTION 3:**

This will be slight design change. It is similar to Solution 2 but only make sense if you are doing only add operations. So what you can do is create another temp `List` and in `Keylistener` add to this list. And once your iteration is through make `synchronized` block and move all the objects from temp `List` to `List` you use for iteration. This WILL NOT block your KeyListener but iterator will see old data as in Solution 2. It might have better performance as compared Solution 2.

So choose the solution which make sense for your design.

Ref:

[Java Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)
[COW](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Comment: I'm not sure that this will avoid ConcurrentModificationException if an event is added while a for-loop is iterating over the list.  Does anyone know? But I'm sure that a CopyOnWriteArrayList would avoid it in a for-each-loop  since the iterator remains on the old copy even when a new event is added to the list.

Comment: No, this won't avoid the `ConcurrentModificationException`.  A COW list would work though (assuming it's the behaviour you want).

Comment: There is no point to use a Synchonized List here. It doesn't matter if the individual operations are atomic, which is all a `synchronizedList` does: the iteration needs to be *exclusive* wrt. modifications. It would be better in this case to just use `synchronized` on the same object -- say the *original* ArrayList, or an explicit lock object -- in both cases, and skip `synchronizedList` entirely. I personally like COW for this -- it's so "lazy" :p

Comment: BTW it is required to use `Collections.synchronizedList` in here as if dont then `KeyListener` wont gonna be blocked and we ll have the same exception. Even though our iterator is in the `synchronized` block.

Answer (score 1):

For an event-queue, I generally use [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) **as a queue fits really well in this model** (much better than a List/ArrayList).

A queue is much easier to use in a threaded manner like this because there is no "iterating" the queue in a list sense: just push an item, grab an item. Both of these operations can be atomic (and relatively easy to synchronize).

I prefer to approach this model with the assumption/requirement that once an object consumed from the queue it can be considered "owned" by that thread (the thread that puts the object there should relinquish the object until it gets the object back, via another queue, if ever).

> ConcurrentLinkedQueue:
>
> An unbounded thread-safe queue based on linked nodes. This queue orders elements FIFO (first-in-first-out) ... A ConcurrentLinkedQueue is an appropriate choice when many threads will share access to a common collection [but works "just fine" for 2] ...

The [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) is another structure that could be used, although it's more of a "general" structure. I am not sure which is "faster", but considering that I've never had a problem with the ConcurrentLinkedQueue, it's my first staple choice, for reasons given above. There are also different concurrency-safe queue implementations, including bound-queues, also found in the [concurrent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package.

Of course, to keep in "old school", just synchronize *on the same object* when 1) modifying (or iterating) the collection in the EDT (whenever it occurs) 2) iterating the collection in the game thread. This will make the operation *mutually exclusive* and prevent this exception. One "downside" is that this may block the UI thread, depending how long the loop keeps the lock. This same approach can also be used around normal non-synchronized queues.

Happy coding.